# What is the best design for set of elements with different type parameters in Scala

Tags: scala, types, type-parameter

I am new to Scala.  I know the basic of type theory.

The problem is to create a graph object of nodes with callbacks.

The following is simplified version of the current implementation.
This is a part of a library.

It works, but full of `Any`.
I think it is impossible to get rid of all `Any`, but I suspect there is a better way.

Especially, `CallbackNode` takes covariant type parameter, but callback's type is contravariant, then becomes `Any`.
But callbacks are everywhere in user code, so it is better to have type `A` for usability.

Let me know how you will design against such problem.

```
trait Graph[N] {
  var nodes: List[N]
  var edges: List[Edge[N]]

  def register(node: N) { nodes = node :: nodes }
  def dependants(node: N): Seq[N] = { ... }
}

object MyGraph with Graph[CallbackNode[Any]] {
  ...
}

class CallbackNode[+A](getter: => A) {
  var cache: Option[Any]
  MyGraph.register(this)

  def onChange(callback: Any => Unit) { ... }
  def update() {
    val v = getter
    storeInCache(v)
    dependants.foreach { n => n.notify() }
    callbacks.foreach { c => c(v) }
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: You could replace `var cache: Option[Any]` with `private[this] var cache: Option[A]`.

Comment: Can your graphs have edges between nodes of different types? Like between `CallbackNode[A]` and `CallbackNode[B]`?

Comment: @senia's advice removed all `Any`s!  I did not know `private[this]` specification.  Thanks.

Comment: @tomy_kaira: do you need more help here? Or should I create an answer with explanation about `private[this]`?

Comment: @senia I wrote an answer according to your advice.  Did it violate the rule?  I appreciate your explanation.  It must be better than mine.

Comment: @tomy_kaira: Not at all. You should accept your answer to indicate the problem is solved. You could add to your answer that covariance and contravariance is about interface of class, not about internal implementation, and you should define method or field as `private[this]` to remove it from interface - `private` (without `[this]`) methods and fields are part of interface since they could be called from companion object or other instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @senia's comment, I found the method.

In this case, `callbackList` and `cache` can be `private[this]` (instance private. which is invisible from other instance of the same class).
Then I made types in methods to be invariant.

```
class CallbackNode[+A](getter: => A) {
  private[this] var cache: Option[A]
  private[this] var callbackList: List[A => Unit]
  MyGraph.register(this)

  def onChange(callback: A => Unit) { ... }
  def update() {
    val v = getter
    storeInCache(v)
    dependants.foreach { n => n.notify() }
    callbacks.foreach { c => c(v) }
  }

  ...
}
```

Graph is still `CallbackNode[Any]` as nodes.
`MyGraph` is for internal use, so this `Any` is not a large problem.
The idea from shapeless will solve this problem, too, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept that per a given graph instance all the callbacks have the same type A, you can move the type as a part of the graph definition.  Since you probably don't want, then you need to use the first common ancestors, which might end up to be Any.

There is however way in Scala, even if it is not trivial, to have data structures which behaves like collections but preserve types as you are looking to do. You should have a look to @MilesSabin shapeless library to understand how it's done.  https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless

Once you master Shapeless concepts such as HList and HMap, you can develop HGraph and open source it :)

Comment: Thank you for interesting information.  In this case, making variables private was enough, but I will try to understand the awesome shapeless library.